# How to calculate modulo of large integer (number having 25000 digits)

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, big-numbers

I'm looking for solution to a problem to calculate modulo of very large number that can contain 25000 digits or less (n) with 10 digit number (m). ( n % m ) ?

Pointer to appropriate theory resource is also welcome.

Thanks

Comment: You mean on a computer? You'll probably have to use a bignum library of some kind – in which case this is just a programming question, rather than mathematics.

Comment: Do you have the numbers in some special form or are you asking about the general case?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė General Case.

Comment: Why is the case of large number different from the case of small numbers? As Zhen asked, is  this a programming problem?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Yes, this is a programming problem but I do not want to use bignum library. Because I think there must be interesting property of modulo which can do the task efficiently. Any good source for modular arithmetic in and out?

Comment: @Jaini: I don't understand your comment. What would the existence of an "interesting property" have to do with whether you want to use a bignum library that implements it? How do you plan on obtaining the big number anyways?

Comment: If I had to guess, the big number is obtained by exponentiating something, in which case the most efficient course of action is to keep reducing modulo $m$ while computing $n$ in the first place!

Answer (score 4):

As small as your modulus is, I don't think you can do significantly better than ordinary long division (typically done in base $2^{64}$) to compute the remainder.

However, you can optimize the individual steps; e.g. by using an algorithm like Barrett reduction to obtain the remainder of a 2 digit x 1 digit remainder calculation.

Writing efficient (or even simply *correct*) division code is a very irritating task; unless you really, *really* like this sort of programming or are using a specialized algorithm for a very special case, you are certainly better off with a good (or even just *decent*) bignum package.